# Dragging sprite leaves trails

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a simple AS class:

```
package Bubbles 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.LineScaleMode;
    import flash.display.CapsStyle;
    import flash.display.JointStyle;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        public function Test()
        {
            var g = graphics;

            g.lineStyle(12, 0xEEEEFF, 1.0, true, LineScaleMode.NONE, CapsStyle.NONE, JointStyle.MITER);
            g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 60, 60, 10, 10);

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
        }

        private function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            startDrag();
        }

        private function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            stopDrag();
        }
    }
}
```

is added used in class set as stage's class in `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` handler:

```
            var t = new Test();
            t.x = 20;
            t.y = 20;
            addChild(t);
```

Now when I start the application both in browser or in flash player and start to drag the object I see trails like on the image:
[image: trails]

Stage only has that green rectangle on it. If I remove it nothing changes. If I change line thickness to 6 trails does not appear, at 7 and higher they appear. You can check SWF here: http://hg.n0rd.com/bubbles.html. How do I make it work correctly?

Update:
If I change that rectangle shape to something star-like with sharp angles, trails appear even on lower thickness values (trails appear when thickness == 3 or more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it to work with

graphics.lineStyle(12, 0xEEEEFF, 1.0, true, LineScaleMode.NORMAL, CapsStyle.NONE, JointStyle.MITER);

I changed LineScaleMode.NONE to LineScaleMode.NORMAL.

Hopefully you don't have to set that?

Answer (score 0):

You are not redrawing the background at each draw. Because of that, the item border stays drawn on the background when it is not overwritten by the next draw.

Comment: That does not explain why no trails left when thickness is 6 or less. Also I have never ever bothered with redrawing background before and I had no problems - it's flash, it should work automagically.

Comment: @nOrd If you are not supposed to redraw the background, then it seems like a bug of the calculation of the pixels to be redrawn when the shape is moved. What happens when you move a square with sharp angles and wide border ?

Comment: Redrawing the background to clear the screen in flash is a horrible idea (when using the drawing api) this will just stack another layer on top of the previously drawn graphics and *all* of it will be redrawn the next frame, quickly bringing your framerate to a grinding halt. Use `graphics.clear()`to clear the screen instead.